# How to code "a[i]=b[c[i]]" on ARM NEON SIMD Intrinsic function

Tags: arm, simd, intrinsics, neon

I'm trying to translating this C/C++ code to SIMD Intrinsic function.

```
for(int i=0 ; i < length ; i++)
    A[i] = B[C[i]];
```

I can translate below code (C/C++)

```
for(int i=0 ; i < length ; i++)
    A[i] = B[i];
```

to SIMD code (using Intrinsic function)

```
for(int i=0 ; i < length-16 ; i+=16) {
    uint8x16_t v0 = vld1q_u8(A+i);
    vst1q_u8(A+i, v0);
}
```

I know that keyword is interleaving to solve this problem. But i can't find solution.

Thanks.

**Edit**
`For more information`

```
unsigned char A [32] = {0,}; // Output Array
unsigned char B [20] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}; // An array with values to pass to A Array
unsigned int C [32] = {19,15,11,10,5,3,6,4,5,19,10,14,16,14,8,9,10,20,11,1, 0, 3, 5, 19, 20, 11, 13, 9, 30, 31, 7}; // An array with the index information of the B array.
```

Is there any Intrinsic function that can make the following code form?

```
int length = 32;
For (int i = 0; i < length-8; i+=8)
{
    Uint8x8_t v_idx = vld1_u8 (C + i);
    Uint8x8_t v = func (A, v_idx); // func (uint8_t, uint32x4_t)
    vst1_u8(C+i, v);
}
```

Will output `20, 16, 12, 11, 6, 4, 7, 5, 6, 6, 20, 11, 15, 17, 15, 9, 10, 11, 21, 12, 2, 1, 4, 6, 20, 21, 12, 14, 10, 31, 32, 8`

**[Note]**
A and B are uint8_t * types because they are images with values between 0 and 255, and C is a uint32_t * type because they are indexed by B index.

Comment: That's not interleaving, unless `C` has a particular structure. In general it's a gather, I hope it isn't. What is `C`?

Comment: @harold I knew the wrong information, Thanks. `C` is an array that has an index value of `B`.

Comment: So it's a general gather, as far as I know NEON doesn't have that

Comment: You are right. After all, I chose to load 16 values each using vld1q_lane_u8 when loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit hard to be sure since you didn't provide a lot of information, but `vqtbl1_u8` might be what you're looking for.  It's AArch64-only, though `vtbl1_u8` is available on armv7.

A quick example:

```
int main (void) {
  uint8_t bp[] = { 1,  1,  2,  3,  5,  8, 13, 21 };
  uint8_t cp[] = { 0,  2,  4,  6,  1,  3,  5,  7 };

  uint8x8_t b = vld1_u8(bp);
  uint8x8_t c = vld1_u8(cp);

  uint8x8_t a = vtbl1_u8(b, c);
  uint8_t ap[8];
  vst1_u8(ap, a);

  for (int x = 0 ; x < 8 ; x++)
    printf("%3u ", ap[x]);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Will output `1   2   5  13   1   3   8  21`

Comment: It has helped a lot. Thank you. However, the length of the `B` and` C` arrays is more than 10 million. As you can guess, `C` Array is an array with index information of` B` Array. I have added a question for more information.